# How can default env variable in gnu makefile target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to do something like this

```
test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER:-$${ANOTHER_VAR}}
```

but its not working. it always come as blank

EDIT:

This works fine. provided i export BUILD_NUMBER in shell before invoking make command

```
test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}
```

THese are not working . They both give blank BUILD_NUMBER

```
test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER:-$${ANOTHER_VAR}}
```

and

```
test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER:-55}}
```

Comment: @user657267 why is that duplicate, i can pass ENV variable if its single but i am not able to set to default. that questions is only passing ENV , it has nothing to do with defaults

Comment: post a complete example of what you're trying to do, I can't understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to expand variables in bash rather than in the makefile, you'll need to escape the expansion otherwise make is going to look for a variable literally called `BUILD_NUMBER:-${ANOTHER_VAR}` or `BUILD_NUMBER:-55`

```
test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=$${BUILD_NUMBER:-$${ANOTHER_VAR}}

test.install:
        export BUILD_NUMBER=$${BUILD_NUMBER:-55}}
```